# Testflight - continue testing after 30 days?

Tags: ios, testing, core-data, testflight

We are looking at running a test campaign for our iOS mobile app with a few hundreds users, using TestFlight.

(We cannot use an Apple Enterprise account)

The test will last 50 days and there is a 30-day limitation for test flight builds.

the documentation says:

> To continue testing after the 30-day period expires, upload another
>   build. Internal testers automatically receive an update notification
>   when the new build is available. To distribute the new build to
>   external testers, you resubmit it to Beta App Review. As soon as it is
>   approved, you can send the external testers an update email by
>   clicking Send Invites from the External Testers column on Builds,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

So, in theory, we could test version 0.9.0 for a month, then build and distribute 0.9.1 and have people update (yes a little clunky).

The question is does it really work and what happens to local app data when updating? things like coreData and NSUserDefault?

It would be great to have some sort of absolute confirmation than those are fine.

I cannot fully test that because update behaviour might be different before and after passing that 30 days limit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, posting two version works. The app data should not be affected. Make sure your testers are aware of this limitation and do update before the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Note, If you update the build number instead of the version, Testflight groups it together and automatically sends the update. When you change the version you have to log in to iTunes Connect and enable Testflight on the new version.
If you want to skip the 30 day limit, you can use other services for distribution, such as Fabric's Beta. This requires registering each device though, and you're limited to 100 devices on the developer portal. If you need more, you could create multiple developer accounts. There shouldn't be a fee anymore if you're just testing on a device.

And your app data will not be affected by the update (unless you make a change to your app). I have done this (hit 30 day limit and then sent update) before without any problems.